# Make names not selected, anonymous

Tags: matrix, powerbi, switch-statement, dax, alias

Please help, I am building a power bi report, where I have to reference a table I created for a different name for a Supplier.

E.g. if on Supplier slicer I select supplier A, then all other suppliers shown on that table should change automatically

The View I want

[image]

In reality the data would look like

[image]

But there would be a slicer where I select the supplier name who I am presenting to, but dont want them to view competitor names , only competitor results, without having to make these changes manually in excel.

THANK YOU GUYS

Comment: Are you looking for anonymize all customer name except the selected one?

Comment: Yes please , so on a selection page , if the user selects supplier A, noting all slicers will be synced, then every table/ graph should use the alternative name for the other suppliers. I have also created a table in power bi , with alternative or "anonymous" names.